# Does Get-Help tell you the type returned by a cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get the return type for a PowerShell cmdlet from the `Get-Help` command?  I prefer to get this information without actually invoking the command and use `GetType()` on it.  Seems like the object return type should be in the documentation somewhere?

Example:  I type `Get-Help Get-Content`.  Where in the documentation does it tell me it returns a `String` Object? or `String[]` object?

Is there some flag I need to provide to `Get-Help` to get this information?

Answer (score 6):

`Get-Command` can also be helpful in this scenario:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command Get-Content |Select OutputType

OutputType
----------
{System.Byte, System.String}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run `Get-Help -Name Get-Content -Full`, you'll see all the help members.  For your question, there is an `OUTPUTS` field:

```
OUTPUTS  
    System.Object, System.String  
        Get-Content returns objects that represent the content that it gets.
        The object type depends on the content type. If you use the Stream
        parameter, the cmdlet returns the alternate data stream contents as
        a string.
```

An array isn't really a type all on its own, but you can force anything to return an array to you by wrapping it in an array literal:

*File.txt*

```
This is one line of text
```

Command:

```
@(Get-Content -Path File.txt)
```

Now you can access the `.Count` and other array type members and when you use `-match` (for example), it will return the full string if it is successful instead of `$True`/`$False`

Comment: I just discovered that you can type:  "get-help -showwindow get-content"  and it implicitly added the -full when popping up a second window..

Comment: @BillMoore Yes it does!  You can also use the `-Online` switch to pull up your default browser pointed at the help source which has the same information, but in a browser, so you can search it more easily.